# Two UserControl dependency properties that must be different

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I'm working on `UserControl` where I have `MaximumAngle` and `MinimumAngle` properties.

```
// MinimumAngle

public double MinimumAngle
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumAngleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MinimumAngleProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumAngleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MinimumAngle", typeof(double), typeof(RoundGauge), new PropertyMetadata((double)0, MinimumAnglePropertyChanged));

private static void MinimumAnglePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RoundGauge rg = (RoundGauge)d;
    rg.CreateTickLines();
}

// MaximumAngle

public double MaximumAngle
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumAngleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MaximumAngleProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumAngleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MaximumAngle", typeof(double), typeof(RoundGauge), new PropertyMetadata((double)180, MaximumAnglePropertyChanged));

private static void MaximumAnglePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RoundGauge rg = (RoundGauge)d;
    rg.CreateTickLines();
}
```

These properties must be different, because my `CreateTickLines` method is going crazy when it has to deal with zero.

What I can do with this?

Comment: Register a [CoerceValueCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.coercevaluecallback(v=vs.110).aspx) with property metadata.

Comment: You could probably use a `ValidateValueCallback` as described on the MSDN page [Dependency Property Callbacks and Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally there are two approaches you can take to deal with this issue.

## Approach I

Use coercion mechanism to modify the values so that they're never equal. You can register a `CoerceValueCallback` through property metadata. In the callback method you could modify the value by, for example, adding/subtracting `double.Epsilon`:

```
private static void CoerceMinimumAngle(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
    if(d.GetValue(MaximumAngleProperty).Equals(baseValue))
        return (double)baseValue + double.Epsilon;
    else
        return baseValue;
}
```

Coercion callback for `MaximumAngle` would be symmetrical.

## Approach II

Handle this special case in your `CreateTickLines` method. Depending on the purpose and implementation details of your control there are many ways in which you can accomplish that. Here's several that come to my mind (assuming that I interpreted your code correctly):

- Do nothing, i.e. add a check at the beginning of `CreateTickLines` method and simply return if both properties are equal
- Clear all existing tick lines and do not create any new ones
- Create a single tick corresponding with the value
- More generally - only execute the part of the code that does not "go crazy" and does not depend on the part of the code that does "go crazy"

My personal advice would be to take the second approach, especially if this requirement exists not because such state is invalid, but rather because it poses an inconvenience for you to handle.